# Encrypting with RSA existing modulus and exponent C#

Tags: c#, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt some data with a modulus and exponent from a server API. I tried a few different ways and I haven't been getting anywhere. So far, this is what I have. There is more to the modulus that I am omitting.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RSAParameters result = new RSAParameters())

        Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("MjMwMDM5MDYyODE5NDc3MTQwODE5MzM0MTM4NzgzNjUyNTQ1MTU5NzAxNTY5NjIyMTc4OTc1NzIwODUzNjQwODY2NjM3NTI4NDQ1NDYzODU5MzY0NDY4MjIzMjk0MTI3NTg4NjY5NTQ5NjkxOTgxNTIxOTMwMzEwMTg4Njg4MjMzNjUzOTYwNzkzMzkzNjQwMDEwNjk3MDA3ODA4MDc3NDM1MTc1ODcwMjk2NzQ2ODQzMjAyODgwNzgxNzYzNDcxNTY2OTc0NDQ2MjY2NDA2MTQxOTU1Nzk4MjQwOTMwMjIxNzA4NTkzNDk5NjQ0MDM0ODc3ODQzODYxOTgyOTAyOTYxMzI0NzkyODAzNjQ1Mzk2MTk0ODcyNz=");
        Exponent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("10001");

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data");

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        RSA.ImportParameters(result);
        var encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(bytes, true);
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedData);
    }
}
```

Currently this is getting me a bad data exception, and I am not sure why. I also tried it in python, but the result was not correct. I am open to using another language if I need to. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a [mcve]? The code doesn't appear to compile for me, as `RSAParameters` does not implement `IDisposable`, and `Modulus` and `Exponent` are unknown variables, as you haven't used a proper object initializer. This leads me to think that there might be problems with your code we're not seeing. And would it be possible for you to post an actual, expected-to-work modulus Base64 string?

Comment: Your usage of ASCII is also worrisome, are you sure the exponent are supposed to be those bytes?

Comment: Your Base64 string is not valid.  It is not the correct size (a multiple of 64).  Where did the string come from?

Comment: @jdweng, base64 string size does NOT have to be a multiple of 64 but a multiple of 3! it's a totally valid base64 string.

Comment: Its length is 375 (chars)

Comment: I copied code straight from posting and got an exception.

Comment: @jdweng Me too and that's very interesting. The link in my answer can decode it.

Comment: I mentioned that I left out part of the Base64 string out, since it is an actual public key. Other than this, and the error I mentioned, this code should compile. Also, I am totally new to cryptography, and most of this is based off stack overflow answers etc. so if I'm not using best practices let me know and I'll try to fix them.

Comment: I just put the code into my IDE and realized that the top using statement was invalid. I had added it to the question because I thought I had seen it done somewhere, but I guess I was wrong. I'm removing it from the question.

Comment: Dear Douglas. When the Exponent is set as in my answer, there should be no errors. The only thing left is to test the decryption part to see whether the encryption was successful or not.

Comment: @MarkusDresch: Every 3 bytes are encoded as **4** base 64 characters, so a multiple of 4 is correct. It is thus not a valid string.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk thanks for correcting, i confused the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1:

It is very interesting but

```
Convert.FromBase64String("MjMwMDM5MDYyODE5NDc3MTQwODE5MzM0MTM4NzgzNjUyNTQ1MTU5NzAxNTY5NjIyMTc4OTc1NzIwODUzNjQwODY2NjM3NTI4NDQ1NDYzODU5MzY0NDY4MjIzMjk0MTI3NTg4NjY5NTQ5NjkxOTgxNTIxOTMwMzEwMTg4Njg4MjMzNjUzOTYwNzkzMzkzNjQwMDEwNjk3MDA3ODA4MDc3NDM1MTc1ODcwMjk2NzQ2ODQzMjAyODgwNzgxNzYzNDcxNTY2OTc0NDQ2MjY2NDA2MTQxOTU1Nzk4MjQwOTMwMjIxNzA4NTkzNDk5NjQ0MDM0ODc3ODQzODYxOTgyOTAyOTYxMzI0NzkyODAzNjQ1Mzk2MTk0ODcyNz=");
```

fails with invalid legth.

https://www.base64decode.org/ decodes this base64 content to

```
2300390628194771408193341387836525451597015696221789757208536408666375284454638593644682232941275886695496919815219303101886882336539607933936400106970078080774351758702967468432028807817634715669744462664061419557982409302217085934996440348778438619829029613247928036453961948727
```

I thought at first that the site gave me the hexadecimal representation of the bytes this decodes to. Unfortunately, it just prints out a STRING.

This means that we need to apply one more transformation (I had done this in my code when I put the answer here, but did not show how it should be done in yours)

This is the code that should work for you too:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RSAParameters result = new RSAParameters()
    {
        // If the following is working on your system:
        Modulus = HexStringToByteArray(Convert.FromBase64String("MjMwMDM5MDYyODE5NDc3MTQwODE5MzM0MTM4NzgzNjUyNTQ1MTU5NzAxNTY5NjIyMTc4OTc1NzIwODUzNjQwODY2NjM3NTI4NDQ1NDYzODU5MzY0NDY4MjIzMjk0MTI3NTg4NjY5NTQ5NjkxOTgxNTIxOTMwMzEwMTg4Njg4MjMzNjUzOTYwNzkzMzkzNjQwMDEwNjk3MDA3ODA4MDc3NDM1MTc1ODcwMjk2NzQ2ODQzMjAyODgwNzgxNzYzNDcxNTY2OTc0NDQ2MjY2NDA2MTQxOTU1Nzk4MjQwOTMwMjIxNzA4NTkzNDk5NjQ0MDM0ODc3ODQzODYxOTgyOTAyOTYxMzI0NzkyODAzNjQ1Mzk2MTk0ODcyNz=")),
        // And since it is not working on my environment:
        // Modulus = HexStringToByteArray("2300390628194771408193341387836525451597015696221789757208536408666375284454638593644682232941275886695496919815219303101886882336539607933936400106970078080774351758702967468432028807817634715669744462664061419557982409302217085934996440348778438619829029613247928036453961948727"),
        Exponent = HexStringToByteArray("010001")
    };

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data");

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        RSA.ImportParameters(result);
        var encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(bytes, true);
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedData);
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL POST:

The problem is here:

```
Exponent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("10001");
```

This is actually the hexadecimal representation of bytes 0x 01 00 01 (3 bytes)

Note: Convert.FromBase64String() has failed for the input provided by you. That's why there was confusion over this. It failed on my local too, so I used the [on-line decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) which succeeded decoding it,

I used this decoded value for the modulus to reproduce.

```
    public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(hexString.Length / 2);
        for (int i = default(int); i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            stream.WriteByte(byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

And then;

```
Exponent = HexStringToByteArray("010001")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the base64 to hex problem. I had a hex string, but converted it to decimal while trying to figure this out, and used it thinking it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Not only Base64. Did you see the Exponent part of the code? That's the real fix `Exponent = HexStringToByteArray("010001")`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I'm working at testing it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you convert the hex string to a byte array? ASCII.GetBytes is not correct. The method in my answer is ok.

Comment: There is no longer any errors, but for some reason, the server is still not accepting the response. That's probably a problem on my end still. If you have any suggestions, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I used the method in your answer to do the conversion.